# Show UniData SELECT results that are not record keys

Tags: database, unidata, uniquery

I'm looking over some UniData fields for distinct values but I'm hoping to find a simpler way of doing it. The values aren't keys to anything so right now I'm selecting the records I'm interested in and selecting the data I need with SAVING UNIQUE. The problem is, in order to see what I have all I know to do is save it out to a savedlist and then read through the savedlist file I created.

Is there a way to see the contents of a select without running it against a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of it at the time but I basically needed something like SQL's [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement since I just needed to view the unique values. Replicating DISTINCT in UniData is explained here, https://forum.precisonline.com/index.php?topic=318.0.

The trick is to sort on the values using [`BY`](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/d3nt/91/refman/access/by_modifier.htm), get a single unique value of each using [`BREAK-ON`](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/d3nt/91/refman/access/break_on_modifier.htm), and then suppress everything except those unique values using [`DET-SUP`](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/d3nt/91/refman/access/det_supp_modifier.htm).

```
LIST BUILDINGS BY CITY BREAK-ON CITY DET-SUP
CITY.............
Albuquerque
Arlington
Ashland
Clinton
Franklin
Greenville
Madison
Milton
Springfield
Washington
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanted to visually look over the data, use `LIST` instead of `SELECT`.

The general syntax of the command is something like:

```
LIST filename WITH [criteria] [sort] [attributes | ALL]
```

So let's say you have a table called `questions` and want to look over all the `author` for questions that used the tag `unidata`. Your query might look something like:

```
LIST questions WITH tag = "unidata" BY author author
```

Note: The second author isn't a mistake, it's the start of the list of attributes you want displayed - in this case just author, but you might want the record id as well, so you could do `@ID author` instead. Or just do `ALL` to display everything in each record.

I did `BY author` here as it will make spotting uniques easier, but you can also use other query features like `BREAK.ON` to help here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorting on the field should help for some of the smaller files. It doesn't really help with my larger files though since I still have one value per record and some of my files have well over 1,000,000 records.